# Url Parsing/Converting With Mod Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite a url so that if a user enters or clicks on a link that looks like:
**"mysite.com"**
OR
**"http://mysite.com"**
OR 
**"www.mysite.com"**
*They are taken to* **"http://www.mysite.com"**.

I am currently using the following code inside my .htcaccess file but it appears not to do anything:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond !^www\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|favicon\.png|media|robots\.txt|crossdomain\.xml|css|js)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|favicon\.png|media|robots\.txt|crossdomain\.xml|css|js)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_params=$1 [L,QSA]

<filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    #Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\\.(css)$">
    #Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\\.(js)$">
    #Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, private"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
    #Header set Cache-Control "max-age, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
```

*Error fixed.

My site now loads but for instance if I go to mysite.com it doesn't redirect me to http://www.mysite.com.

Comment: What is the error reported in your server error log?

Comment: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Comment: Ok solved that error I had "space" in one of my rules. However it seems not to be working on my urls, doesn't do anything I enter one of those I want converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it. It turns out I had the rewrite conditions in the wrong order.

Correct way:
RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon.ico|favicon.png|media|robots.txt|crossdomain.xml|css|js)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_params=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond !^www.mysite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon.ico|favicon.png|media|robots.txt|crossdomain.xml|css|js)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]